# Wordpress post in two categories. How to show once in home?

Tags: php, wordpress, post, filter, categories

I have a loop that displays the posts from Wordpress by category, but some posts are in two categories so on the home page where all the posts are shown, these post appears twice.

Example:

- "Example Post" is in "Category One" and "Category Two"
- When you see the posts of "Category One", "Example Post" is there. The same happens when you see the posts of "Category Two".
- But when you click "see all posts", "Example Post" shows twice (because it's in two categories)

Does anyone know how to "hide" this repeated posts?

This is the loop:

```
<?php 

    $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'products', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );

    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>


        <?php 
          $my_post_child_cats = array();
            foreach((get_the_category()) as $childcat) { 
                if (cat_is_ancestor_of(3, $childcat)) { ?>


                <div class="item"  data-groups='["all", "<?php echo $childcat->cat_name; ?>"]'>
                    <div class="pindex">
                        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                            <div class="pimage">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                                <div class="pro-title">
                                    <h4><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h4>
                                    <p>Read more</p></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <?php } ?>

                    </div>
                </div>

        <?php } } ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
```

This code will get all the posts and add the category name with this piece: `<?php echo $childcat->cat_name; ?>`

Then in the home page I've created a filter by category which will take the posts by that `$childcat->cat_name;`, but when you click "All posts" it will get the posts twice as it has two categories

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to do this? Perhaps it's not a WP issue.

Comment: Better to put this in [Wordpress SE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @ShaunakShukla To be fair SO seems to get quicker responses and better results than WPSE in my experience.

Comment: @patie you'd need to show us some code for this since what you are describing could be carried out in an infinite number of ways.

Comment: @PhillHealey I know it. If the question is also asked in WSE, it would be good for making a stronger community for wordpress!

Comment: @PhillHealey I've added the code, so you can see how I've done it

Comment: @ShaunakShukla I've added the code, so you can see how I've done it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store each post name in an array and then only output it if it's not already been displayed. Something like this:

```
<?php 
$array[];
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'products', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );

if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>


    <?php 
      $my_post_child_cats = array();
        foreach((get_the_category()) as $childcat) { 
            if (cat_is_ancestor_of(3, $childcat)) { ?>


            <div class="item"  data-groups='["all", "<?php echo $childcat->cat_name; ?>"]'>
                <div class="pindex">

                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() && !in_array(get_the_title(), $array) ) { ?>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <div class="pimage">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                            <div class="pro-title">
                                <h4><?php echo get_the_title();
                                 $array[] = get_the_title();
                                 ?></h4>
                                <p>Read more</p></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>

                </div>
            </div>

    <?php } } ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

You'll possibly need to tweak the code to suit your need but what this code does is essentially grabs the name/title of the post and stores it in an array:

```
$array[] = get_the_title();
```

Then on subsequent loops checks to see if the title of the current looped post is in the array:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() && !in_array(get_the_title(), $array) )
```

If it is, then nothing should be output. If it isn't then we output the relevant content and store the title of the post in to the array.

Comment: Thank you @PhillHealey, but the problem with that is that I have lots of posts and every week I add more... so storing each post as an array couldn't be an option...

Comment: @patie Have you tried the code above? It doesn't really matter how many posts you have unless you are talking about millions.

Comment: How would you store each post? Could you show me an example? @PhillHealey

Comment: It's all there in the code I gave. That is all that you need. Replace the code you gave with the code I gave above and that should more or less take care of everything.

Comment: I copied the code you gave me, but I'm getting the same result as before...  @PhillHealey Any idea why?

Comment: Ok, but that should be enough for you to work with. It's fairly simple code, that'll you just need to tweak to get it working.

Comment: @patie I've updated my code to give a bit of an explanation as to what's happening. Also, I've fixed a small typo that means the array wasn't being checked. This should work now, if not it's only a simple job to tweak for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody still looking answer how to remove duplicate posts. First you need create empty array, than in first loop add all id of post. In the second loop check if post id are in array and its true than remove current post id from array. There a code

```
<?php 
 $do_not_duplicate = array(); //CREATE EMPTY ARRAY
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'products', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );

if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

<?php $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; //FILL ARRAY?>
    <?php 
      $my_post_child_cats = array();
        foreach((get_the_category()) as $childcat) { 
            if (cat_is_ancestor_of(3, $childcat)) { ?>

            <?php if ( in_array( $post->ID, $do_not_duplicate ) ) {
             do_not_duplicate = array_diff($do_not_duplicate, array($post->ID)); // CHECK ARRAY AND REMOVE ID
            ?>
            <div class="item"  data-groups='["all", "<?php echo $childcat->cat_name; ?>"]'>
                <div class="pindex">
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <div class="pimage">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                            <div class="pro-title">
                                <h4><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h4>
                                <p>Read more</p></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>

                </div>
            </div>

    <?php } } } ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: This is a low quality answer. It's not clear what you are saying as you don't explain what your code does. Break it down a little and give some explanation. Please see the SO rules if you are unsure.